# Full text searching in SQL Server 2008 Express Advanced

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have recently installed SQL Server 2008 Express Edition with Advanced Services on XP Pro but am having trouble getting full text searching to work with an restored database. The database was originally created in SQL Server 2005.

When I call a stored proc that uses the full text index then I get the following error: Full-Text Search is not installed, or a full-text component cannot be loaded.

This is my db version:
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (Intel X86) 
    Jul  9 2008 14:43:34 
    Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition with Advanced Services on Windows NT 5.1  (Build 2600: Service Pack 3)

When I run: SELECT DATABASEPROPERTY('DBNAME','ISFULLTEXTENABLED')

I get: 1

Also, when I look in the advanced properties for the db server in Management Studio I see both the "Default Full-Text Language" and "Full-Text Upgrade Option" properties. However, when I go to SQL Server Configuration Manager I don't see the "MSSQLFDLauncher" service.

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Cheers,
Iain

Additional: I tried to "generate SQL" for the full text index but I got the following error message: Full-text is not supported on this edition of SQL Server. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

This is very odd because according to the MS website it does suppor full text indexes: http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/default.aspx#Installation_Options

Comment: I have this same problem now. I just upgraded from Express to Express With Advanced Services. I wonder if a fresh install would have worked. Did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to tweak database compatibility level? [link text](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1436)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.

The compatibility level was set to 80 so I tried setting it to 90 and to 100 but that didn't solve my problem.

When I tried setting it to 110 I got the following error: Valid values of the database compatibility level are 80, 90, or 100.

100 is SQL Server 2008.

Comment: sorry, my bad, it should be 100. The latest error ("fulltext is not supported) you mention might be connected with the fact that fulltext indexes can't be scripted. Have you double checked if the fulltext engine is installed and running under accounts with sufficient rights? Otherwise I'm running out of suggestions.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and managed to solve it by:

- You need installation files for "SQL Server Express with Advanced Services". If you don't have a CD you can download and extract the EXE (right click and Extract files).
- Go to Control Panel > Add or Remove Programs
- Find SQL Server and open it. (It asked me a question along the lines of "uninstalling this while other people are using it will cause them some pain" - it was a bit scary but I said yes OK and it then asked the usual question: do I want to unininstall or change)
- Question: uninstall or change (Answer: change).
- Click "Add Features"
- Browse for the install media. In this case we can locate the place where we unzipped the installer for "SQL Server Express with Advanced Services" (note it must be extracted or it won't like it)
- Go through a bunch of crapping around steps. You will then be asked "install new instance" or "add features to existing instance" (choose add features).
- At the "Features" step you can check the box "Fulltext Search" (hooray!!)
- Finish the wizard and everything should now work, run this sql to confirm: 
  select SERVERPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')